# Solving an inequality with a parameter

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

I'm trying to solve a parametric inequality:

$\frac{x-p}{p-2}>1$ for x.

I tried multiplying it by $(p-2)$ and I got $x>2p-2$, but  I don't know what to do next. Are my steps correct? And if so, how do I continue?

Thanks

Comment: In general, you cannot multiply by $p-2$, because it can be negative. So, as I shown below, just consider two cases and everything will be okay :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{x-p}{p-2}>1 \iff\frac{x-p-p+2}{p-2}>0 \iff \frac{x-(2p-2)}{p-2}>0$. Therefore if

$p>2$ the answer is $x>2p-2$

$p<2$ the answer is $x<2p-2$

Comment: Isn't there a mistake? $x-p-p+2$ is $x-2p+2$

Comment: @LukasT Thank you. Fixed.